# R.java file not updating in android

Tags: java, android

While cleaning the project the R.java file is getting deleted and after while I am building the project not getting R.java file

Comment: check if there is an error in any of the layouts. if you do not see any error mark, go to show views, and select error log and there you will get the error

Comment: did you tried eclipse restart?

Comment: This the common question . Please check various answer over here

Comment: Check for any subtle error in **any** xml file. Also check that your file names don't contain invalid characters (such as "**-**" or **Upper Case** letters)

Comment: yes I tried  restarting eclipse even then there is no chenge

Answer (score 1):

Such cases appear when there is some issues with your layouts. Check the error log to find any errors. Clear them and build again.